# Multiple errors - Don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const double LaborCharge = 35;
    const double TaxonPartsandSupplies = .09;
    string CustomerName;
    double HoursofLabor = 4.50;
    double CostforLabor = 97.00;
    double PartsandSupplies = 8.73;
    double TotalAmountDue = 263.23;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "enter CustomerName";
    cin >> CustomerName;
    cout << "enter TCostforLabor";
    cin >>  LaborCharge * HoursofLabor;
    cout << "enter TPartsandSupplies";
    cin >>  PartsandSupplies * .09;
        cout << "enter TotalAmountDue";
    cin >> TPartsandSupplies + TCostforLabor;

    cout << endl;
}
```

not part of ..**errors** below

> Error C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
>   header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?      32
>   Error (active)    E0020   identifier "TCostforLabor" is undefined     28
>   Error (active)    E0020   identifier "TPartsandSupplies" is undefined 28
>   Error (active)    E0349   no operator ">>" matches these operands 26   Error
>   (active)  E0349   no operator ">>" matches these operands     24

Comment: Where do you define the variables `TCostforLabor` and `TPartsandSupplies`? This error should have been pretty obvious to figure out.

Comment: And using Visual Studio the default project settings is to use precompiled headers. The auto-generated source (if you opted for that) should have contained `#include "pch.h"` as the very first non-comment line. Add it back in. This error should have been very easy to find out about with a *little* searching.

Comment: Disable precompiled headers in project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some major errors. Admitted, I don't know what your compiler wants for the first error, but anyway

1. problem

   ```
   cin>> LaborCharge * HoursofLabor;
   ```

   This won't work. You can't assign an input of **std::cin** to an product of an multiplication. This would result in an endless debug session, so standard types don't let this happen. I suppose you want to do this.

   ```
   cin >> LaborCharge;
   LaborCharge *= HoursofLabor;
   ```

   Same for the other **std::cin** lines...
2. problem

   You need to declare the variables **TPartsandSupplies** and **TCostforLabor**.

Comment: thank you,your advice helpd get rid of my cin errors

Comment: The first error is because the OP has the compiler setting for precompiled headers turned on. It's on by default in VS compilers  Either the OP needs to turn that off (the sensible option) or they need to supply a precompiled header.